# Exact an Inexact Differntials.

Tags: differential

How can the addition of two(or more) inexact differential give an exact differential? Moreover, if an exact differential represents a linear map, what does an inexact differential represent(analogously)?

Lets take the **2-D Case**.

We know **Green's Theorem:**
$$
\oint\limits_C P dx+Q dy= \iint\limits_D(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y})dx \ dy
$$

In a particular resource(Richard Fitzpatrick, Thermodynamic notes) it was mentioned that if $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} \ne \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$, then the differential is not exact.

This is a sufficient condition. However, is it a necessary condition? **What is the necessary and sufficient condition?**

Comment: It is a sufficient and necessary condition if the domain of the form is a [star domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain), or in the more general case if it is a [simply connected space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space)

Comment: Could you guide me to the proof resource, if you may?

Comment: Or explain it in a bit simple way, as i am a 2nd year undergraduate.

Comment: $\omega=x\,dy\,,\;\eta=y\,dx$ are two non-closed (therefore non-exact) differentials whose sum is exact. For the rest of the question you should read about Poincare's lemma. We cannot repeat everything in MSE. Some things need patience.